RTF string seems to load in richtextbox from bottom toward the top. not top to bottom like picturebox
i am trying to load a rtf string into a RTB. It loads from bottom upwards. and my picture box is from top to bottom when it fills and grows the control. How do i change RTB to have the same behavior? i omitted the rtf string because it reached my character limit.
and a picture of the control
picture of control loaded with rtb string (image loaded is cut off)

Here i moved the control down to accomodate its "growth" upwards

Here is the loaded image with the moved control, you can see the rest of it not just the bottom. almost like it loads from bottom to top instead of growing from top to bottom like a picture box.

How do fix this loading problem?

You might not be able to change the render direction. Your picture might be larger then your page, section, or control allows. Design by default for your screen shots section and RTB to take up the entire page. Then set options to allow CanShrink.

both are canShrink and CanGrow are set to true
